# Assign random team out of 16 teams to a random person out of 8 people

Tags: python, arrays, list, random

I am trying to assign two teams out of 16 teams to 8 people out of 8 people,

Here is what I have:

```
import random    
person = ['Ashton', 'Danny', 'Martin', 'Yves', 'Nick', 'Cormac', 'Thierry', 'Ciaran']    
team = ['France', 'Switzerland', 'England', 'Slovakia', 'Germany', 'Ukraine', 'Spain', 'Czech Republic', 'Croatia', 'Italy', 'Republic of Ireland', 'Sweden', 'Russia', 'Wales', 'Belgium']    
namesTeams = {}    
for x in person:    
    teamName = team[random.randint(0, len(team) -1)]    
    namesTeams[x] = teamName    
    team.remove(teamName)    
print(namesTeams)
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `random.choice([List])`

Example:

```
import random

persons = ['Name', 'Name', 'Name', 'Name', 'Name', 'Name', 'Name', 'Name']

teams = ['France', 'Switzerland', 'England', 'Slovakia', 'Germany', 'Ukraine', 'Spain', 'Czech Republic', 'Croatia', 'Italy', 'Republic of Ireland', 'Sweeden', 'Russia', 'Wales', 'Belgium']

combinations = {p: random.choice(teams) for p in persons}
```

The result is a dictionary.

If you want to avoid duplicates you have to iterate over the list.

```
combinations = {}
for p in persons:
    team = random.choice(teams)
    combinations[p] = team
    teams.remove(team)
```

Comment: Yes, this works for python3 and python2.7

Comment: There is a typo in your code, it's `teams`, not `team`. Moreover, this will only yield one result `{'Name': 'Ukraine'}` for instance.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the typo. No this will create a dictionary assigning each name a random team

Comment: I was confused since `'Name'` is the only key in the dictionary. But you're right, provided all keys are different, this will yield the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

So the thing you're trying to do is just *pick random "the length of `names`" elements from `teams`*. In this case, you should use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
>>> import random
>>> person = ['Name', 'Name', 'Name', 'Name', 'Name', 'Name', 'Name', 'Name']
>>> team = ['France', 'Switzerland', 'England', 'Slovakia', 'Germany', 'Ukraine', 'Spain', 'Czech Republic', 'Croatia', 'Italy', 'Republic of Ireland', 'Sweeden', 'Russia', 'Wales', 'Belgium']

>>> random.sample(team, len(person))
['Ukraine', 'Russia', 'England', 'Croatia', 'France', 'Spain', 'Italy', 'Wales']
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

> `random.sample(population, k)`
>
> Return a *`k`* length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set. Used for random sampling without replacement.
>
> Returns a new list containing elements from the population while leaving the original population unchanged. The resulting list is in selection order so that all sub-slices will also be valid random samples. This allows raffle winners (the sample) to be partitioned into grand prize and second place winners (the subslices).

---

If you want to assign two teams per person, I'd suggest you [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) the `team` list, then split the list into 2 sized chunks, and put the result into a dictionary:

```
{person: two_teams for person, two_teams in 
                   zip(people, [team[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(team), 2)])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice). In your case, you could have the following:

```
import random
names = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3']
teams = ['France', 'Switzerland', 'England', 'Slovakia', 'Germany', 'Ukraine', 'Spain', 'Czech Republic', 'Croatia', 'Italy', 'Republic of Ireland', 'Sweeden', 'Russia', 'Wales', 'Belgium']
people = []

for name in names:
    people.append(random.choice(names), random.choice(teams))
```

`people` will be a list of tuples of a name and a team.

Comment: This only creates one combination, and a combination is required for all people.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a dictionary with names attached to teams, without duplicates

```
import random

person = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6', 'Name7', 'Name8']
team = ['France', 'Switzerland', 'England', 'Slovakia', 'Germany', 'Ukraine', 'Spain', 'Czech Republic', 'Croatia', 'Italy', 'Republic of Ireland', 'Sweden', 'Russia', 'Wales', 'Belgium']
namesTeams = {}

for x in person:
    teamName = team[random.randint(0, len(team) - 1)]
    namesTeams[x] = teamName
    team.remove(teamName)

print(namesTeams)
```